# Explicitly declare "movement" and "movement.endPosition"?

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

Cesium Sandcastle demos illustrate the use of "movement" and "movement.endPosition" to fetch
Cartesian2 coordinates of the mouse moving. One example is the ["Picking" demo in Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/?src=Picking.html):

I am new to Javascript.
Implicit declarations and variable hoisting were not my cup of tea so far!

So my question is:
Based on the Picking Sandcastle demo provided above, what could I do to declare "movement.endPosition" explicitly, for the same purpose of showing longitude/latitude on mouse-over? I am not comfortable with the "movement" object showing up without being explicitly declared first.

My research has led me to the Cesium.CameraEventAggregator object, which contains a method named "currentMousePosition".

Lines 25-27 are from the demo:

```
    // Mouse over the globe to see the cartographic position
    handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
    handler.setInputAction(function(movement) {
        var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(movement.endPosition, scene.globe.ellipsoid);
```

I have tried to replace "movement.endPosition" as follows:

```
    // Mouse over the globe to see the cartographic position
    handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);
    handler.setInputAction(function() {
        var mousePos = Cesium.CameraEventAggregator(scene.canvas); 
        var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(mousePos.currentMousePosition, scene.globe.ellipsoid);
```

This results to no information shown on mouse-over.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thank you in advance, apologies for the long winded problem statement!
Manny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScreenSpaceEventHandler` listens to events happening in screen-space (namely mouse, touch, and pointer events).  When you call `.setInputAction`, you're assigning a callback function that you wish to have called in response to those events.

JavaScript allows the function to be declared inline, which may be part of the confusion.  Below, I've refactored this function to break out this callback as a real function called `onMouseMove`.

With this function broken out, it may be more clearly visible that `movement` is declared as the sole argument to be passed to the `onMouseMove` callback function.

```
// Declare entity first.
var entity = viewer.entities.add({
    label : {
        show : false,
        //...
    }
});

// Declare function "onMouseMove" that takes one argument called "movement".
// This could be declared above, but, it makes use of the entity, so for
// code readability it should appear after "entity" is declared.
function onMouseMove(movement) {
    var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(movement.endPosition, scene.globe.ellipsoid);
    if (cartesian) {
        var cartographic = Cesium.Cartographic.fromCartesian(cartesian);
        var longitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.longitude).toFixed(2);
        var latitudeString = Cesium.Math.toDegrees(cartographic.latitude).toFixed(2);

        // NOTE: Using "entity" from outer scope here.
        entity.position = cartesian;
        entity.label.show = true;
        entity.label.text = 'Lon: ' + ('   ' + longitudeString).slice(-7) + '\u00B0' + '\nLat: ' + ('   ' + latitudeString).slice(-7) + '\u00B0';
    } else {
        entity.label.show = false;
    }
}

// Construct a ScreenSpaceEventHandler.
handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);

// Finally, assign function "onMouseMove" as the callback for the event.
handler.setInputAction(onMouseMove, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```

Take a look at that very last line.  If you replace the word `onMouseMove` in that line with the entirety of the function declaration, the code will be the same as the original on Sandcastle.

So, `movement` is an object that was constructed inside of `ScreenSpaceEventHandler` for the purpose of communicating an event to the callback function.  In this particular case, `movement.endPosition` is an instance of a `Cesium.Cartesian2` object, with `x` and `y` values representing the mouse movement's resulting location in screen space.

The `viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(...` function can take any `Cesium.Cartesian2` value of any screen location you wish to consider.  For example:

```
var myCustomScreenLocation = new Cesium.Cartesian2(300, 200);
var cartesian = viewer.camera.pickEllipsoid(myCustomScreenLocation, scene.globe.ellipsoid);
```

This would pick a location 300 pixels from the left, 200 pixels from the top of the Cesium window.

---

Edit: Here's [another demo](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=dVFfa8IwEP8qoS+tTFL2Oqtsk4KCxUGdbFAYMT01LL2UJq3rxr770kZhKt5T7u735+7SsIo0Ag5QkTFBOJApaFEXdN3XAp/36VShYQKh8gejDBvLkUybRNUaXpQWRii0ddfZM8zlpVzKKwBMS8YhbgDNzIECZ001BwTKmRXQg17pqEI1mDmWtXninUmwrdE9CtVAYYUG5CdDYuNqIDvACUQB87M5O0KueN03d2Bi2eOe23ke+EYpuWF2VSrQrjxbJQsydpwu/N6FvD0Qn9xd29IvW/XJ+612O3JSGf4Ob11n1ZZAk+VrGn8ky3XsLuINvUibVsLECTyKolSVIXUlA0pDA0UpmQEdbmr+CYZy3Z8yCk+kKBcNEfk48y4+NfMIt4Nq29nWUqbiGzJvEoUWf0aTiuUCd8sGKsnaDrK/nyxckVIahTa9Zh3P+U/xDw) that shows how to display current mouse/touch/pointer coordinates.

```
var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer');
var lastMousePosition;

var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.scene.canvas);

handler.setInputAction(function(movement) {
    lastMousePosition = movement.endPosition;

    document.getElementById('toolbar').innerHTML =
        'Mouse X: ' + lastMousePosition.x + ' Y: ' + lastMousePosition.y;

}, Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE);
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch @emackey, I was hoping you would show up and answer! I will experiment on the results of declaring two handlers now. I want to understand how many "movement" instances would be created in that case and how to distinguish between them. I understand there is no point in creating multiple SpaceScreenEventHandler's, it is just a theoretical thought!

Comment: Thanks to @emackey, I think I have found how to explicitly get the handler's `movement.endPosition`. After declaring the handler: `let handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(scene.canvas);` I can get the mouse position with `handler._primaryPosition`. Thank you once again!

Comment: You probably don't want to read from `_private` variables like that.  I added another code sample to the bottom of my answer, give that a try.